# Is it possible to save to my disk from the photos app?

Tags: icloud, photos.app, macos

In the past, If I've ever wanted to take a photo on my iPhone and move it to my mac, I'd have to use the files iOS app or google drive. I recently had an idea, instead of uploading the photos to somewhere, I could just save them from the macOS photos app to my disk after they were backed up.

The problem is, there doesn't seem to be an option anywhere that lets me save the photo from the app to my disk. Is this even possible?

I'm using macOS High Sierra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag one or more photos from the Photos app to somewhere in Finder, such as a Finder window or Desktop.

Comment: I actually didn't think of that before, perfect!

Answer (score 2):

The other way, which takes a (very) few more steps, is to click on the photo you want to save to your disk. Then, in Photos, go to File > Export, and choose to export the edited photo (shift - command - E), or the original unmodified file. You will then be presented with some options as in the picture below, and when you click "Export," you can even choose where to save the picture. Works great.
[image]